# Prevent iterator name from being confused with symbol passed into function body

Tags: programming, scoping

I have a massive amount of code with lots of `Table` and `Sum` inside a `Module`.  Each with their own iterators, and I have completely lost track of all of them.  But if the user calls the function with an argument matching the name of the iterator, the code no long works as intended.

An example is this function that is supposed to return a list of three repeated symbols:

```
function[x_] := 
Module[{},
  answer = Table[x, {i, 1, 3}];
  Return[answer];
]
```

For example:

```
function[a]
(*{a,a,a}*)
```

But this can be broken by

```
function[i]
(*{1,2,3}*)
```

Obviously, `Table` is confusing the input `x=i` with its own iterator `i`.  What is the fool-proof fix for this?  Is there a solution without:

1. Finding the names of all the iterators and listing them all as private variables inside `Module`?
2. Finding all the iterators and renaming them `longAndComplicated1`, `longAndComplicated2`, etc.?

Comment: Maybe `\[FormalI]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks If you are proposing using Formal Symbols for the `Table` iterators I think that would actually make the situation worse.  In most evaluation it can be assumed that Formal Symbols will not have assigned values, but `Table` will not respect the `Protected` attribute therefore it *will* (temporarily) gives value to Formal Symbols.  In my opinion that is even more confounding.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know about the `Protected` issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of `Module`'s capability to localize variables.

```
f[x_] := Module[{i}, Table[x, {i, 1, 3}]]
f[i]
```

> ```
> {i, i, i}
> ```

Also, with `i` localized, you don't need to use distinct iterator names in different iteration constructs.

```
g[x_] :=
  Module[{i, a, b},
    a = Table[x, {i, 3}];
    b = Table[x^3, {i, 2}];
    {a, b}]
{g[i], g[a], g[b]}
```

> ```
> {{{i, i, i}, {i^3, i^3}}, 
>  {{a, a, a}, {a^3, a^3}}, 
>  {{b, b, b}, {b^3, b^3}}
> ```

Further, note that you don't need to use `Return` if you use the semicolon ( ; ) operator properly. (Yes, semicolon is an operator in *Mathematica*, not a terminator.) See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/3066) for more information on the semicolon operator. Actually, it likely you will benefit from ***all*** answers given on the page I have linked to.

Comment: Thanks!  Where can I find more information on *when* I must use the 'Return' function?

Comment: @QuantumDot. That is a very good question. I think it deserves own posting, so I have done so and given my answer which is way too long for a comment anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`Table` and `Sum` scope their variables in the manner of `Block`.  Effectively your code is like this:

```
f[x_] := Block[{i = 5}, x]

f /@ {a, i}
```

> ```
> {a, 5}
> ```

This is actually a very useful aspect of `Table` but in this case it is also the source of your problems.

Since you must localize the iterators one of the best solutions is the one you reject out of hand which is to put all iterator variables in the `Module` specification.  Perhaps some meta-programming with satisfy you:

```
SetAttributes[localize, HoldAll]

localize[(s : Set | SetDelayed)[LHS_, RHS_]] :=
  Union @@ Cases[Unevaluated@RHS, (Table | Sum)[_, x__] :> Hold[x][[All, 1]], {0, -1}] //
    Pick[#, #, _Symbol] /. _[x__] :> s[LHS, Module[{x}, RHS]] &
```

To use it wrap your definition in `localize`:

```
localize[
  ff[x_] := {Sum[x, {i, 4}], Table[x, {i, 3}, {j, 2}]}
]
```

Test:

```
ff[i]
```

> ```
> {4 i, {{i, i}, {i, i}, {i, i}}}
> ```

The definition we created:

```
Definition[ff]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you do not want to have to comb through this block of code manually to find which variables are being used as iterators. Fortunately, you can do this with pattern matching.

Say we have this definition:

```
ClearAll@"Global`*";

function[x_] :=
 Module[{},
  notanswer = Sum[j^2, {j, 10}];
  answer = Table[x, {i, 1, 3}];
  answer];
```

You can work with the definition programmatically using `DownValues`.

```
Evaluate@DownValues@function // Inactivate;
```

I have used `Inactivate` to avoid any undesired evaluation. Now, you can search this expression for structures that include iterators:

```
Cases[%,
  iter : IgnoringInactive[_Table | _Sum] :> iter[[2, 1]], 
  Infinity] // Union
```

> {i, j}

Then you can just plop that into the first argument of `Module`.